# Android choose custom fonts

Tags: android, fonts

How to give a user the ability to select a font? In "preferences", I want to have change Font and there list of fonts.

I have set the font in this way:

```
mTimerLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label); 
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Fonts/digital-7i.ttf");
mTimerLabel.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've described the correct model of changing typeface in textView. I can't understand the problem you've faced. Call preferences for a textView, choose font (or its id) and set it.

Comment: I do not understand how to select the font id. That is, if the user selects "blabla.tff" how to set it.

Comment: As for me the easiest way is to create a Map that will contain position in preferences as a key and the font name. For example:   0 - bla.ttf     1 - blabla.ttf   ...

Comment: then by choosing a preferences field you'll get its ID and get the font name from Map

Comment: In preferences you may set some view. For example listview. Its items have next IDs: 0,1,2,etc. then when you call onItemClickListener for your listView You can get the position, you've clicked. and the position will be the ID of your font

Answer (score 2):

You will have to store the ttf in your assets folder. Also, AFAIK you cannot name any folder in uppercase chaacters- the way you have done in `Fonts`. Rest of the approach is fine. You might want to check the value you are storing in preferences using Logcat.

Answer (score 1):

store the font name i.e. digital-7i.ttf in the preferences, when user will select any font you can replace the name from preferences and use your code like this.

```
SharedPreferences Settings = getSharedPreferences(
            "<PREF_NAME>", MODE_PRIVATE);
    fontName = Settings.getString("<KEY>", "digital-7i.ttf");


mTimerLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label); 
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Fonts/"+fontName);
mTimerLabel.setTypeface(typeface);
```